# How do the mineral achievements work?

Tags: spiral-knights

In Spiral Knights, there are a number of achievements like this:

> Deposit *X* minerals into a gate

Does it have to be the *same* gate, or does it count them all?

I.e. if I deposit 2000 into one gate, and then 500 into another gate a week later, will I get the achievement for putting 2500 into a gate or do I have to deposit all 2500 into one gate?

Also, once I get the achievement for putting 100 into a gate, does that count towards the achievement for 500, meaning that I only have to put in 400 more for that achievement?  And so on?

Answer (score 5):

These achievements work on total minerals deposited.

The only kink is that you don't have any in-game statistic of how many minerals you've previously dumped. Just keep at it, and you should get it eventually.

Like many steam achievements, you accrue progress to each of these simultaneously. Your first 10 minerals count for your 500 AND 1 million mineral achievements.